# Matrix Multiplication Error

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to use * to multiply 2 matrix but I got this error

For example

```
a = [ 0 0 1 1 0
      0 1 1 0 0 ]

b = [ 1 1.5
      0 1 ]
```

`b*a` gives me the result, but `a*b` gives me error "Requested matrix multiplication requires arguments to be conformant."

Why is that?

Comment: -1 This is not a programming issue. It's basic math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because matrix multiplication is only defined if the number of columns in the matrix on the left of the multiplication is the same as the number of rows in the matrix on the right.  That is, for the expression

```
A * B
```

to be valid (either mathematically or Matlabilly) `A` must be of dimensions `m*n` and `B` must be of dimensions `n*k`, producing a result of dimensions `m*k`.